# Passing data accross Classess with out instantiating the class

Tags: python, oop

I have two classes that need to pass data between each other. The first class instantiates the second. The second class needs to be able to pass information back to the first. However I cannot instantiates the `ClassOne` again from class two. Both classes are running off a shared timer where they poll different things so while they share the timer they cannot share the objects they poll.

My current solution (that works) is to pass a method to `ClassTwo` and used to send data back up but I feel this might be a bit hack-ey and the wrong way to go about it.

```
classOne():

    def __init__(self,timer):
        self.classTwo = classTwo(self.process_alerts,timer)
        self.classTwo.start

    def process_alerts(alert_msg):
        print alert_msg 


classTwo():

    def __init__(proses_alerts,timer)
        self.process_alerts = process_alerts  # <----- class ones method

    def start(self):
        check for alerts:
            if alert found: 
                self.alert(alert_msg)


    def alert(self,alert_msg):
        self.process_alert(alert_msg)  # <----- ClassOnes method
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hint for the future: put markers in comment, such that the code is still valid :).

Comment: You can add the `@staticmethod` annotation to `process_alerts`.

Comment: Why don't you inherit class Two from class One? `class Two(One): ...`

Comment: Because the timer application i am using overloads 3 methods both classes need to have these methods in them and return different information.

Comment: I don't see the contradiction.

Comment: @P.Siehr why would use inheritance here ? It wouldn't solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: class Two needs to have methods of class One, which is the perfect application of inheritance. Second task: class Two needs to pass information back to class One. And since you have a member object of class Two in class One, you have access to all information of class B as well. So I don't see how one would not use inheritance.

Comment: @P.Siehr "class Two needs to have methods of class One" : not at all. `ClassTwo` needs to _call_ methods of it's container `ClassOne` instance, it's composition, not inheritance.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Your solution does solve OP's problem, but so does inheritance. IMO it is a matter of taste, with both methods differing slightly. // Is there something in the question, that I missed?

Comment: @P.Siehr: yes, you missed the fact that the OP wants to establish a communication between two instances of two distinct classes.  The fact that `objA` calls some method on `objB` certainly doesn't mean nor imply in any way that `objA` "is a" `objB`. And FWIW I still wait for you to explain how inheritance would solve the OP problem... Remember, you need _two_ distinct objects `a` and `b`, `a` must call `b.start()` (NOT `a.start()`)  and `b` must call `a.process_alert()` (NOT `b.process_alert()`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147614/discussion-between-p-siehr-and-bruno-desthuilliers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing prevents you from passing the current `ClassOne` instance (`self`) to it's own `ClassTwo` instance:

```
class ClassOne(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.two = ClassTwo(self)
        self.two.start()

   def process_alert(self, msg):
       print msg

class ClassTwo(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def start(self):
        while True:
            if self.has_message():
                self.parent.process_alert(self.get_message())
```

Note that in this context "parent" means it's a containment relationship ("has a"), it has nothing to do with inheritance ("is a").

If what bugs you is that `ClassOne` is responsible for instanciating `ClassTwo` (which indeed introduce a strong coupling), you can either change `ClassOne` so it takes a factory:

```
class ClassOne(object):
    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.other = factory(self)
        self.other.start()
```

# etc

and then pass `ClassTwo` as the factory:

```
c1 = ClassOne(ClassTwo)
```

So you can actually pass anything that returns an object with the right interface (makes unittesting easier)

Or - at least in your (I assume striped down) example - you could just make `ClassOne` pass itself to `ClassTwo.start()` and explicitely pass `ClassTwo` instance to `ClassOne`, ie:

```
class ClassOne(object):
    def __init__(self, other):
        self.other.start(self)

    def process_alert(self, msg):
        print msg


class ClassTwo(object):
    def start(self, parent):
        while True:
            if self.has_message():
                parent.process_alert(self.get_message())


c2 = ClassTwo()
c1 = ClassOne(c2)
```

Or even simpler remove the call to `ClassTwo.start` from `ClassOne` and you don't need any reference to a `ClassTwo` instance in `ClassOne.__init__`:

```
class ClassOne(object):

    def process_alert(self, msg):
        print msg


class ClassTwo(object):
    def start(self, parent):
        while True:
            if self.has_message():
                parent.process_alert(self.get_message())


c1 = ClassOne()
c2 = ClassTwo()
c2.start(c1)
```

which is as decoupled as it can be but only works if `ClassTwo` only needs `ClassOne` instance in `start()` and methods called from `start` and `ClassOne` doesn't need to keep a reference on the `ClassTwo` instance either.

Answer (score 2):

You could remove/minimize the coupling between the classes! I found this sort of [architecture](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2014-12-03-what-is-message-queuing.html) maps really well to sharing data by communicating across a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html).

By using Queue you can decouple the two classes.  The producer (`ClassTwo`) can check for messages, and publish them to a queue.  It no longer needs to know how to correctly instantiate a class or interact with it,  it just passes a message.

Then a `ClassOne` instance could pull messages from the queue, as they become available.  This also lends well to scaling each instance independent of each other.

```
ClassTwo -> publish to queue -> Class One pulls from queue.
```

This also helps with testing as the two classes are completely isolated,  you can provide a Queue to either class.

---

Queues also usually provide operations that support blocking until message becomes available, so you don't have to manage timeouts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In my case Bruno`s answer did the trick without implementing anything extra so i marked his as correct.